# Swift 4 バーコードリーダアプリのメタデータ取得について

Tags: swift, swift4

Swiftでバーコードリーダーを作成しており、カメラの起動は問題ないのですが、メタデータが取得できません。
ビルドは成功しています。原因お分かりになりますでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    // Connect as outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

    // Make instance
    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    // Make notification
    let notification = NotificationCenter.default

    // Status for privacy and in-output
    var authStatus:AuthorizedStatus = .authorized
    var inOutStatus:InputOutputStatus = .ready

    // Authorization Status
    enum AuthorizedStatus {
        case authorized
        case notAuthorized
        case failed
    }
    // InOut Status
    enum InputOutputStatus {
        case ready
        case notReady
        case failed
    }

    let x: CGFloat = 0.1
    let y: CGFloat = 0.4
    let width: CGFloat = 0.8
    let height: CGFloat = 0.2

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // interrupt if processing session
        guard !captureSession.isRunning else {
            return
        }
        // privacy authorization for camera
        cameraAuth()

        // Set InputOutput
        setupInputOutput()

        // Check camera is ready
        if (authStatus == .authorized)&&(inOutStatus == .ready) {
            // Set previewLayer
            setPreviewLayer()
            // Start session
            captureSession.startRunning()
        } else {
            // alert
            showAlert(appName: "Camera")
        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    func cameraAuth(){
        let status = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video)
        switch status {
        case .notDetermined:
            AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video,
                                          completionHandler: { [unowned self] authorized in print("First Time", authorized.description)
                                            if authorized {
                                                self.authStatus = .authorized
                                            } else {
                                                self.authStatus = .notAuthorized
                                            }})
        case .restricted, .denied:
            authStatus = .notAuthorized
        case .authorized:
            authStatus = .authorized
        }
    }

    func setupInputOutput(){
        // Set resolution
        // captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.

        // Set input
        do {
            // Obtain devise
            let devise = AVCaptureDevice.default(
                AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera,
                for: AVMediaType.video,
                position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.back
            )

            // where to input
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: devise!)
            if captureSession.canAddInput(input){
                captureSession.addInput(input)
            } else {
                print("Failed to add input to session")
                return
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print("Camera doesn't exist \(err)")
            return
        }

        // Set output
        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        if captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)
            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate((self as? AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate), queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.ean13]
            metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = CGRect(x: y, y: 1 - x - width, width: height, height: width)
        } else {
            print("Failed to add output to session")
            return
        }
    }

    func setPreviewLayer(){
        // Make previewLayer
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect

        // Add preview
        previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        // Add red-frame
    //        let detectionArea = UIView()
    //        detectionArea.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width * x, y: view.frame.size.height * y, width: view.frame.size.width * width, height: view.frame.size.height * height)
    //        detectionArea.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //        detectionArea.layer.borderWidth = 3
    //        view.addSubview(detectionArea)
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        for metadata in metadataObjects as! [AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject] {
            // check whether it's barcode
            if metadata.type == AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13 {
                if metadata.stringValue != nil {
                    print(metadata.stringValue!)
                }
            }
            print("metadataOutput called")

            // metadata
            print(metadata.type)
            print(metadata.stringValue!)
        }
    }

    func showAlert(appName: String){
        let aTitle = "privacy authorization for " + appName
        let aMessage = "Please authorize by Setting>Privacy> " + appName
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: aTitle, message: aMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

        // OK(nothing)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))

        // Open Setting
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Setting", style: .default, handler: { action in UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)}))

        // Display alert
        self.present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

全部のコードをチェックできたわけではないのですが、少なくともここは直さないと動かないというのがあるのでそこだけ示させていただきます。

**ダメ**な部分:

```
        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate((self as? AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate), queue: DispatchQueue.main)
```

delegateを設定する際に型に関するエラーが出た場合、`as?`でキャストしても、殆どの場合、期待される動作にはなりません。ちゃんと設定するインスタンスのクラス(今の場合`ViewController`)を必要なプロトコル(`AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`)に適合させてください。

クラスヘッダには`AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`を追加:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate,
    AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
```

(`AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate`が必要かどうかわかりませんでしたが、とりあえずそのままにしておきました。)

delegateを設定する場合には、キャストはしない:

```
        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: .main)
```

---

本題には関係ありませんが、`cameraAuth()`の中で`unowned`を使っておられますが、`unowned`と`weak`の違い、どんな場合にそれらが必要になるかを十分理解しておられないのではないでしょうか。あなたのコードの場合、`unowned`も`weak`も必要ありません。十分理解できないまま「念のため」で付けるなら`[unowned self]`ではなく`[weak self]`を使用しておくことをお勧めします。(もちろんそれによりOptionalとしての取り扱いが必要。)`unowned`は使い方を間違えると簡単にクラッシュの原因になります。